# Use multer for File-Uploads inside a Express Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I got a working REST-API built with node.js and Express.

Now I need a file-upload endpoint, which accepts uploaded files and processes them.

I am using an Express Router and some Authentication middleware.

server.js (excerpt)

```
var router = express.Router()
app.use("/api", router)

[...]
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //Authentification middleware
    [...]
    next()
})

router.route("/upload")
     .post(function(req, res){
        //upload logic
     })
```

How can I use *multer* to serve the uploaded file as *req.file* (or so), but only in */api/upload* and for authed users?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

I can use

```
var multer = require("multer")
var upload = multer({ dest: "some/path" })

[...]

router.route("/upload")
    /* replace foo-bar with your form field-name */
    .post(upload.single("foo-bar"), function(req, res){
       [...]
    })
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, it also worked.

```
var multer = require("multer")
var upload = multer({ dest: "path" })

router.post("/upload", upload.single("foo-bar"), function(req, res) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I spent a whole lot of time trying to make this work.  `var uploadMulter = multer({ dest: directory }); router.post('/upload', uploadMulter.single("html_input_element_name"),  function(req,res, next) {...` .   There is a line in the Multer repo `In an average web app, only dest might be required,` . Don't believe that line...  you also need the `.single(fieldname)` call...  Many thanks...

Answer (score 2):

In my case i try every thing but it not works but i come over the solution

**app.js**

```
const multer  = require('multer');
const storage =  {
    dest:  'UPLOAD/PATH/'
}
const upload = multer(storage);
app.post('/myupload', upload.single('FILE_NAME'), (req,res)=>{
  res.send('Upload');
});
```

i tried many times with **express.Router()** but it not works that's why i write code in app.js and redirect to another file.